# key not found in keychain error when debugging on local device connected to my windows dev machine

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, keychain, code-signing-certificate

I made some changes to my MAUI app in VS 2022 on Windows 11. I had no trouble testing my app on a locally connected iPhone before, but now when I try to debug the same app (with changes), on the same iPhone, and the same Windows machine, with the same valid certificates in the VS Apple Accounts Details, I get this error:

*iOS code signing key 'Apple Development: B... (...)' not found in keychain.*

Why is it even referring to the keychain when I'm on a Windows machine using VS2022

[valid certificates in the VS Apple Accounts Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJbfM.png)

Also, I'm getting "MSB6006: 'codesign' exited with code 3." error when trying to test/debug on a remote mac machine.
[How do I debug a Maui iOS codesign code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78078656/how-do-i-debug-a-maui-ios-codesign-code-3)